# Obtaining a basis for a given topology. Lemma from Munkres book

Tags: general-topology

> **Lemma 13.2.** Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of open sets of $X$ such that for each
>   open set $U$ of $X$ and each $x$ in $U$, there is an element $C$ of
>   $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C\subset U$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is a
>   basis for the topology of $X$.
>
> **Proof:** We must show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis. The first condition for a basis is easy: Given $x\in X$, since $X$ is itself an
>   open set, there is by hypotheses an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such
>   that $x\in C\subset X$. To check the second  condition, let $x$ belong
>   to $C_1\cap C_2$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are elements of $\mathcal{C}$.
>   Since $C_1$ and $C_2$ are open, so is $C_1\cap C_2$. Therefore, there
>   exists by hypothesus an element $C_3$ in $\mathcal{C}$ sucht that
>   $x\in C_3\subset C_1\cap C_2$.
>
> Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the collection of open sets of $X$; we must show
>   that the topology $\mathcal{T}'$ generated by $\mathcal{C}$ equals the
>   topology $\mathcal{T}$. First, note that if $U$ belongs to
>   $\mathcal{T}$ and if $x\in U$, then there is by hypothesis an element
>   $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C\subset U$. It follows that $U$
>   belongs to the topology $\mathcal{T}'$, by definition. Conversely, if
>   $W$ belongs to the topology $\mathcal{T}'$, the $W$ equals a union of
>   elements of $\mathcal{C}$, by the preceding lemma Since each element
>   of $\mathcal{C}$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ is
>   topology, $W$ also belongs to $\mathcal{T}$.

This lemma from Munkres book "Topology". I was thinking for a while what is the set $\mathcal{C}$ which he defined in the definition but I dont understand.

1) What are the elements of set $\mathcal{C}$?

2) Also, when he is proving the first condition he means that $X\in \mathcal{C}$?

The same question with the second condition.

I was not able to understand what is the element of set $\mathcal{C}$.

Would be very thankful for explanation.

**EDIT:** Namely how he conclude from openess of $X$ that there is some element $C\in \mathcal{C}$?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your question doesn't really make sense. The set $\mathcal C$ is *some* collection of open sets of $X$ such that for each open set $U$ of $X$ and each $x$ in $U$, there is an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C\subset U$. For instance, if $X$ is $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, $\mathcal C$ might be the set of all open intervals.
2. No. He means $x\in C$.

Concerning your final question, since we are assuming that $\mathcal C$ is a collection of open sets of $X$ such that for each open set $U$ of $X$ and each $x$ in $U$, there is an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C\subset U$ and since $X$ itself is an open subset of $X$, then, for each $x$ in $U$, there is an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C\subset X$.

Comment: Maybe you are right that my question does make sense since I don't understand what is the set $\mathcal{C}$? For example, when I am saying the set of integers less than 10 then I am meaning that $\{x\in \mathbb{Z}:x<10\}$, right? But what is the set $\mathcal{C}$ here?

Comment: @RFZ It is not **one** specific set. Munkres is saying that **every** set $\mathcal C$ that satisfies a certain condition is a basis for the topology of $X$. This is as if I wrote “if $n$ is a natural number, then $n^2-n$ is even” and you asked me which number $n$ is.

Comment: I know that is not specific set! For example, I cannot understand how he proving that the first condition of base is true. It is so confusing!

Comment: I cannot understand the nature and the structure of this set $\mathcal{C}$

Comment: For you, the expression “for each open set $U$ of $X$ and each $x$ in $U$, there is an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C\subset U$” has no meaning?

Comment: It has meaning but it cannot help me to understand the nature of this set. I am having big trouble with it

Comment: For instance, $A=\{x: \text{for} \quad x \text{something holds}\}$ I understand it easily. But is it possible to write out set $C$ in the same form?

Comment: @RFZ No, because thats the way of defining **one** specific set. I suggest that you try to verify that the set of all opn intervals of $\mathbb R$ satisfies the condition from my previous comment.

Comment: The example with open sets i undestand but cannot understand my question.

Comment: $\mathcal{C}:=\{C: \forall \ \text{open} \ U \ \text{in} \ X, \forall{x}\in U \ \exists C\in \mathcal{C} \ \text{such that } x\in C\subset U \}$. Am i right?

Comment: No, because **again** that would define **one** specific set $\mathcal C$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83253/discussion-between-rfz-and-jose-carlos-santos).